# File upload failing when streamed from GCP, but works fine if streamed from local

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, google-cloud-storage, form-data

I have this piece of code, which is meant to upload a file from my (NodeJS) server to a third-party:

```
// file: upload.js
import axios from 'axios';
import FormData from 'form-data';

import { upload } from './upload.js';

export const upload = url => async readStream => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', readStream);

    const response = await axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url,
        data: formData,
        headers: formData.getHeaders()
    });

    return response.data;
};
```

If I run the code above by passing the stream as returned by Google Storage, like this:

```
// file: main.js
import { Storage } from '@google-cloud/storage';

const referenceToFileOnStorage = new Storage({ projectId: 'my-project-id' })
    .bucket('my-bucket')
    .file('/my/file/path/on/storage.txt');

const remoteReadStream = referenceToFileOnStorage.createReadStream();
const thridPartyAPI = 'https://thrid-party.api/v1/file/upload';

upload(thridPartyAPI)(remoteReadStream)
    .then(response => console.log('success', response))
    .catch(error => console.error('error', error));
```

I end up catching this error:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (/opt/megazord/node_modules/.pnpm/axios@0.21.1/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (/opt/megazord/node_modules/.pnpm/axios@0.21.1/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/opt/megazord/node_modules/.pnpm/axios@0.21.1/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:260:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:412:35)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1334:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {config: {…}, request: ClientRequest, response: {…}, isAxiosError: true, toJSON: ƒ, …}
```

If I expand on `error.response.data`, I see this message:

```
{message: 'File empty. Check the document path.'}
```

But if I call the same function (`upload()`) but instead of streaming directly from the GCP, I write on my disk first (and then it stream it from my disk):

```
// file: main.js
import fs from 'fs';
import stream from 'stream';
import { promisify } from 'util';

import { Storage } from '@google-cloud/storage';

import { upload } from './upload.js';

const referenceToFileOnStorage = new Storage({ projectId: 'my-project-id' })
    .bucket('my-bucket')
    .file('/my/file/path/on/storage.txt');

const remoteReadStream = referenceToFileOnStorage.createReadStream();
const tempLocation = '/tmp/file.txt';
const pipeline = promisify(stream.pipeline);
await pipeline(remoteReadStream, fs.createWriteStream(tempLocation)); // 1) I need to await, otherwise I get an error; 2) imagine this top-level await is valid syntax

const localReadStream = fs.createReadStream(tempLocation);
const thridPartyAPI = 'https://thrid-party.api/v1/file/upload';

upload(thridPartyAPI)(localReadStream)
    .then(response => console.log('success', response))
    .catch(error => console.error('error', error));
```

Then it works!

I don't understand why, and I would like it to work without this "download" step.

May it be because of some GCP configuration? The only thing I can think of is that the bucket is private. But if this was the problem, then it shouldn't allow even the download itself, right?

Comment: Hi, is the issue resolved?

Comment: Kind of? I was unable to pindown the problem or fix it, but I was able to get the code to work using the Node standard lib `https` instead of `axios`.

Comment: Can you post what worked for you, so that it helps the community?